# c# exit generic ForEach that use lambda

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, foreach, break

Does anyone know if it is possible to exit a generic ForEach that uses lambda? e.g.

```
someList.ForEach(sl =>
  {
    if (sl.ToString() == "foo")
        break;

    // continue processing sl here
    // some processing code
  }
);
```

This code itself won't compile. I know I could use a regular foreach but for consistency I want to use lambda.

Many thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason it MUST be done this way? I've always been wary of `break;`. Outside of a switch-case, I've never seen need to use them.

Comment: I use `break` and `continue` a lot. Sometimes you just don't want the loop body to execute all he way through, and `break`/`continue` simplifies the code.

Comment: Is there any reason you prefer a Lambda expression for this?

Comment: @Loadmaster: I'm curious, have you actually found code where the ONLY way to prevent the rest of the body from executing was with a break/continue? Nothing else would have achieved the same effect?

Comment: In terms of style, `if(condition) continue;` is IMO cleaner than `if(!condition) { loop body }`

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Of course, it's *always* possible to write code without `break` or `continue`. But that can result in more verbose, less comprehesible, and less efficient code. `break` and `continue` were designed so that you can write concise, efficient code in unusual situations.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sure. But first, note that I recommend against this; I say that a sequence operator should not have a side effect, and a statement should have a side effect. If you're doing something in that ForEach lambda, then make it a statement in the body of a foreach loop rather than making it look like a sequence operator.

That said, here's what you do. First, you write yourself a ForEach that works on arbitrary sequences, not just lists:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach(var item in sequence) action(item);
}
```

And now you write your break like this:

```
someList
    .TakeWhile(x=>x.ToString() != "foo")
    .ForEach(sl=>
    {/*your action here*/});
```

Answer (score 10):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

> The following rules apply to variable
>   scope in lambda expressions:
>
> `snip`
>
> A lambda expression cannot contain a
>   goto  statement, break statement, or
>   continue statement whose target is
>   outside the body or in the body of a
>   contained anonymous function.

Don't know if that helps given the code you posted. The relevant quote is from the end of the MSDN article.

Comment: The most relevant and complete reply yet. I like it!

Answer (score 3):

Warning: the code below is not to be taken seriously and is provided for entertainment purposes only!

You can 'simulate' a continue with an early return like this:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 20)
          .ForEach(n =>
                {
                    if (n == 10) return;
                    Console.WriteLine("This is not 10: {0}", n);
                });
```

That said, I think that side effects within lambda's are a sign that you're doing it wrong. Use a proper foreach instead. Or something like TakeWhile, as Eric kindly demonstrated already.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
        Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
        .Where(x => x % 2 != 0)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: answer with take while also looks good